# Drupal different user type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I want to create two different type of user one is SHOP user and other one is CAD user. CAD user are also similar of SHOP user but they have some extra content access permission. I have created two type of roles of user but main thing is that I need to a option for upgrade the membership. Once click it a mail will goes to admin and admin can approve the user.
On sign up user are normally SHOP user, on accessing  special content a message will be shown there that, "Please upgrade the membership."

Is it possible in drupal? Any existing module for that? Please advice me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hope this module will work for you
[Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole)

Comment: Is it possible to giving option to user to upgrade their user type?

Comment: Main thing is that I have to put a option for user to upgrade their user type, once click on it a mail will fire to admin and admin can approve them

Comment: The Auto Assign Role serves three primary purposes. The first is to provide an automatic assignment of roles when a new account is created. The second is to allow the end user the option of choosing their own role or roles when they create their account. The third is to provide paths that will trigger a specific role when an account is created. The